# Multiple inheritance and generic program

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am reading "Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied" by Andrei Alex., just started. At page 6, it has the following critcism of multiple inheritance:

> The problems with assembling separate features by using  multiple inheritance are as follows:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. *Type information.* The base classes do not have enough type 
>          information to carry out their tasks. For example, imagine you try to 
>          implement deep copy for your smart pointer class by deriving from a `DeepCopy` 
>          base class. What interface would `DeepCopy` have? It must create objects of a 
>          type it doesn't know yet.

I am wondering if this particular critique is flawed.

Interface driven design normally has base class a pure virtual class and the child class implements the interfaces. Take DeepCopy as example, I would do this:

```
struct DeepCopy 
{
   virtual void copy(DeepCopy *src) = 0;
};

class MyClass : public DeepCopy, public AnotherIntf
{
   public:
      virtual void copy(DeepCopy *src); 
};
```

In this example, MyClass is the implementer and it is a real class.

Maybe I miss the point of Andrei's critique here.

What do you think?

Comment: Typical deep copy hierarchies would provide a member like `virtual Base * clone() const = 0` in the base, to be overridden by `return new Derived(*this);` in each leaf.

Comment: If you get to the point to 'interface' deep copy, your design is totally messed up.

Comment: Generally, all I can tell you here is that Andrei's book is certainly a good read, has a few interesting ideas and shows you how little you know about C++. It is very academic. That's a great thing, actually! At the same time, it is not so much about real-life software engineering problems. So don't be surprised if you will rarely find yourself applying anything from the book directly in your own projects.

Comment: Based only on the text posted here, I'd say you're misinterpreting. He's talking about *concrete* base classes that are expected to implement functionality, not interfaces. Even though the mechanism (inheritance) is the same, the concepts are totally different.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, we are on same page.

Comment: @DieterLücking it is more productive to throw an example code.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that Alexandrescu was speaking of an *external* copying facility here, not an intrusive one that requires modification of the classes being copied.  The proper way to implement deep copy for a given class may differ based on the class's implementation, so without a way to provide type information to the external copying facility you can't select the proper approach.

Deep copy may not be a great example here -- his chapters on generalized functors, smart pointers, and multiple dispatch are what I would consider better real-world examples of his policy-based design.