# Why would there be such a requirement for different arguments of the same template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In page 671 of his new book Mr Stroustrup wrote the following sentence:

> Note that there is no requirement that different arguments for the
>   same template parameter should be related by inheritance.

I can understand what the author wrote, but I can't understand the reason why he inserted this comment in the text. I think I'm missing something here, but I don't know exactly what.

Comment: @Columbo He is introducing the definition of templates in §23.2.1.

Comment: @411165 I'd guess he wanted to point out, that templates don't need virtual inheritance or polymorphism to make use of a template parameters' interface.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why would that be relevant?

Comment: @411165 Because it's the whole concept's base of static polymorphism and how templates interact with instances of the template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When introducing the concept of templates, he tries to make clear that its not some kind of **polymoprhism**.

Before template were invented and added to C++ you could write generic code only using inheritance (or multilple inheritance).

Another concept that Mr.Stroustrup certainly want the reader not to confuse with templates is  **interfaces**. In the java comunity for example this is a very popular technique and many books abot OOP explain this concept. Interfaces allow  you to use some kind of generic code with a class, at the condition that the class is defined to implement (not inherit) a specific interface.  All classes using the interface must be related to it.  It's not strictly speaking inheritance, but it's a [kind of substitute to multiple inheritance](http://www.artima.com/intv/abcs.html).

Templates can be used with any object or class without its type being related in advance to anything in common.

Comment: Could you give me some references regarding your second paragraph above?

Comment: I'm satisfied with your answer. I would just mention [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1039904/411165) which also gave me some insight into the issue I've raised. Thanks (+1).

Comment: It's primarily my own experience, when I started with ATT C++2.0, when I had to implement things like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6td5yws2.aspx  .  Apparently it's even mentioned in some books as this SO question suggests:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939939/multiple-inheritance-and-generic-program

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple if we look at the use case of templates from the perspective of someone who is totally new to the concept of templates.

```cpp
int i;
double d;
char c;

print(&i); //prints an integer
print(&d); //prints a double
print(&c); //prints a char
```

From the perspective of someone who does not understand C++ templates, he/she would assume that the prototype of `print` looks something like this.

```cpp
print(SomeBaseType* pdata);
OR
print(void* pdata);
```

However, what happens with templates is with a function template such as

```cpp
template <typename T>
print(T* pdata);
```

for the above use case, the compiler generates three functions during compile-time

```cpp
print(int* pdata);
print(double* pdata);
print(char* pdata);
```

and through **function overload resolution**, the right function gets called.

Thank you for reading.

Disclaimer: A print function might not be the best example.